# MySQL Left Join Count Not working

Tags: mysql, select, count, left-join

I have 2 tables (members, duty_sched)
I want to be able to count how many time each member appears in the duty_sched table.
This is what I have after several weeks searching

```
SELECT 
members.fname, 
members.lname, 
(SELECT COUNT(duty_sched.id) FROM duty_sched
 WHERE 'duty_sched.mbr_id' = 'members.mbr_id') AS shifts 

FROM members
ORDER BY members.lname, members.fname
```

The output I'm getting is all zeros, what I would like it to show me is:

Name         shifts
Bob Smith      4
Jane Johnson   2

Any help I can get will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: hi, I tried your query on dump table that I have. your structure is right. try count(*) and check your where conditions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove the single quotes: `WHERE duty_sched.mbr_id = members.mbr_id)`

You can also write your query with a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT 
    m.fname, 
    m.lname, 
    COUNT(d.id) AS shifts 
FROM members AS m
  LEFT JOIN duty_sched AS d
    ON d.mbr_id = m.mbr_id
GROUP BY
    m.mbr_id                     -- the Primary Key of `members`
ORDER BY 
    m.lname, m.fname ;
```

Comment: the mbr_id is a VARCHAR made up of various columns information, does this make a difference?

Comment: Edit, your question, add the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE members` and real data, a few rows of the table.

Comment: I added a INT column to both tables for ID purposes and once I joined the two INT columns it worked perfectly. Thanks for all you did.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like that

```
SELECT 
members.fname, 
members.lname, 
count(*) FROM duty_sched JOIN members
WHERE duty_sched.mbr_id = members.mbr_id
Group by duty_sched.mbr_id
ORDER BY members.lname, members.fname
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT m.fname, m.lname, IFNULL(A.shifts, 0) shifts
FROM members m 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT mbr_id, COUNT(id) shifts 
           FROM duty_sched GROUP BY mbr_id)  A ON m.mbr_id = A.mbr_id 
ORDER BY m.lname, m.fname;
```